# How to make a list of the user-created python files that a module depends on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, dependencies, doit

I am interested in using [`doit`](http://pydoit.org/) to automate the build process of a python package.
If possible, I would like `doit` to re-execute a task if any of the user-created source files it depends on have changed.
From my understanding, the best way to accomplish this would be to use the `file_dep` key and a list of the dependent source files, however I am having a lot of trouble generating this list.

I've tried using `sys.modules` and `inspect.getmembers()`, but these solutions can't deal with import statements that do not import a module, such as `from x import Y`, which is unfortunately a common occurrence in the package I am developing.

Another route I investigated was to use the [`snakefood`](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) tool, which initially looks like it would do exactly what I wanted, generate a list of file dependencies for every file in a given path. 
Unfortunately, this tool seems to have limited Python 3 support, making it useless for my package.

Does anyone have any insight into how to get `snakefood`-like features in Python 3, or is the only option to change all of my source code to only import modules?

Comment: You can hook `import` to learn about every import, even of modules already imported elsewhere.  But this works only as well as your “test” coverage, since imports can happen (anywhere) inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

doit [tutorial](http://pydoit.org/tutorial_1.html) itself is about creating a graph of python module imports!

It uses [import_deps](https://pypi.org/project/import-deps/) package, it is similar to *snakefood*.

Note that for your use-case you will need to modify `file_dep` itself during Task action's execution. To achieve that you need to pass the `task` parameter to your action (as described [here](http://pydoit.org/tasks.html#keywords-with-task-metadata)).

Comment: of course! Thank you for pointing out `import_deps`. It seems that `import_deps` is almost exactly what is needed, except I need the ability to apply it recursively to find all dependent python files. Do you know if `import_deps` would be straightforward to modify or extend to work recursively?

Comment: I have implemented it recursively and integrated with `doit` in [pytest-incremental](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-incremental). Although I am afraid it is not *straightforward*...